# A smart EML file viewer

Tags: email

We have a bunch of .EML mail files exported from a proprietary CRM of our customer. They don't use that app anymore but they want to add some users to their mail list at some well-known email marketing service.

What we'd like to do is to import these .EML files into some kind of a database. Ideally, we'd like to work with them as if it's Gmail or similar web application - search them, view email threads (emails chained together), group them by response and some CRM marker in the subject and so on and so on.

Is there anything for that? It might be a web-app as well as a desktop software.

We don't even need to send email from that app, only view\search.

Solutions like Mail.app (for Mac) does not seem to be the best choice since it works perfectly with a single .EML file but processing thousands of email manually would take too much time.

Thank you!